# write an algorithm that will accept a temperature as input from a user, and advise the user to wear a jacket

Tags: algorithm, logic, flowchart

write an algorithm that will accept a temperature as input from a user, and advise the user to wear a jacket. Based on the temperature, the algorithm should either tell the user to bring a heavy jacket (colder than 32 degrees), light jacket (between 32 and 50 degrees), or no jacket at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its homework

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Missing a lot of details. In which programming language would you like to do it? For which platform ...

Comment: @AlEmerich this is the question: write an algorithm that will accept a temperature as input from a user, and advise the user to wear a jacket. Based on the temperature, the algorithm should either tell the user to bring a heavy jacket (colder than 32 degrees), light jacket (between 32 and 50 degrees), or no jacket at all.

Comment: @Charles-olivierDemers Yes, the details, i too figured that out. I'd like to use java or the just algorithm flow would be okay. it's from Logic building and effective problem solving

Comment: @0x4f3759df It's no home work. Was asked by a friend of mine, couldn't give in much, so decided to ask it here. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
1. read (temperature)

2. if (temperature<32):
   print("bring heavy jacket")
3. else if f (32<temperature<50):
   print("bring light jacket")
4. else :
   print("no jacket")
```

you have not mentioned any language and its very simple . as simple as your explanation ""

Comment: The language is Java. Okay, Thank you